# Writing a non-static method as a static method

Tags: java, static

I'm trying to write this method as a static method but I don't fully understand how static methods work past them not creating objects to work with.

This is the method I'm trying to convert

```
public void process(String str)
{
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
        char letter = str.charAt(i);
        int index = Character.toLowerCase(letter-'a');
        if (index>=0 && index<26){
            counts[index]++;
        }
    }
}
```

This method just takes a string and records the number of times each letter showed up in the String

Im trying to write this as a static method and I have this method stub

```
public static LetterCounter buildCounter(String str)
{

}
```

Comment: so, what's the prob ?

Comment: The problem is that `counts` is an instance variable, so you can't reference it from a static method.  If that were not a problem it would be a simple matter of adding `static` ahead of the return type.

Comment: is your count array an instance variable or static one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code would require that counts[] be declared as static also, meaning there is only one counts[], and every time you call MyClass.process("blah") it would increase the class variable counts[index]

I am guessing but I think what you are trying to do is create a static "utility' function to return an array of counts for the various charactors in the passed in string?  So something similar to this (untested) code. 
then you would call something like MyUtilClass.process("xxyz");
In this case "static" means that the process does is not associated with an object, it is more like a "function" or "subroutine"

```
public static int[] process(String str) {
    int[] counts = new int[25];
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
        char letter = str.charAt(i);
        int index = Character.toLowerCase(letter-'a');
        if (index>=0 && index<26){
            counts[index]++;
        }
    }
 return counts;
}
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was trying to do.. The counts array is static to those that were wondering. Thanks for all of the help btw guys

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a learning exercise, I wouldn't write any code, but describe what needs to be done:

1. Create a new instance of `LetterCounter`
2. Call an instance method `process` on it, passing `str` that you got in your `buildCounter`
3. Return the instance of `LetterCounter` that you created in step 1.

You are done!

Comment: Isn't @jcvandam trying to write it as a static method? If it's static, there shouldn't be a need to create an instance of it. You should be able to call `LetterCounter.process()`.